# Codeigniter deploy index.php show 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I just deploy my codeigniter project into hosting server. I got this problem.

By right the link should work in this -> http://test.com/quiz/test

When I deploy I need to key this then can work.
http://test.com/quiz/index.php/test

This my server hierarchy

```
public_html
 |-css
 |-js
 |-index.php
 |-quiz
 |---application
 |---system
 |---index.php
 |---....
 |---.htaccess
```

This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Verify that mod_rewrite is enabled on server then you may simply need to restart your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess, this works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Also keep your htaccess inside quiz folder not in application folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, i tried already still can't access. Then I try this and works RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /quiz/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /quiz/index.php?$1 [L] . Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Change the file names to First letter Caps and class name too.

ex: `mas_unit_ctrl` change to `Mas_unit_ctrl`